# Reorder tabs using jquery

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm looking to re-order a set of three content tabs on my homepage using jQuery.

I've figured out how to reorder the tab navigation buttons ok, however the divs that house the panels where the content displays is still showing the old tab orders content.

The code looks like this:

```
<div class="tabs-content">
<section class="content active" id="panel0">
```

my jquery was is looking like this:

```
$(".tabs-content > section #panel0").removeClass("active");
$(".tabs-content > section #panel2").addClass("active");
```

However this is not working, I know its a problem targeting the id of the section html tag. I've checked jquery website but can't locate a solution.

Any help here guys?

Comment: We might need more information for this one. Could you provide a codepen (http://codepen.io/) showing off your issue?

Comment: Hi Colin, I don't have a codepen account. But I will look into setting this up in here, cheers. However in simple terms how do you target the id of a <section> element?

Comment: You can create pens anonymously (and save/share them) just hit "new pen" in the corner. No need for an account.

Comment: Not saying this will solve your problem, but your jQuery isn't currently selecting anything. Where you have 'section #pane10' and 'section #pane12' should be 'section#pane10' and 'section#pane12'

Comment: Hi Trevor, I've just tried that and it works. Not sure what I did before but it didn't seem to work when I tried that previously. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tabs are sequential, you could do something like this.

```
$('.tabs-navigation a').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $('.tabs-content > section').removeClass('active');
    $('.tabs-content > section').slice(index,index).addClass('active');
});
```

This also assumes that your have the class defined properly in css:

```
.tabs-content > section { display: none; }
.tabs-content > section.active { display: block; }
```

I'd like to eliminate those assumptions, but you've not given us much to go on.

Comment: Hi B2K, yes the tabs are sequential, however Trevors answer in the comments above worked out for me thanks.